# How do I move the cursor to a specific row and column?

Tags: vim

`:30` will move my cursor to the beginning of line 30.

How can I tell Vim to place the cursor at line y, column x? Is this possible
without using the arrow keys or `h`, `j`, `k`, `l` keys?

I am running Vim version 7.3.429.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try a number followed by a pipe to get to the specified column in that line.

`80|` should get you to position 80 in that line.

EDIT: If you are looking to go to a specific x,y position, I am not sure on that one.

Comment: Thank you, i forgot to add that as well when using your suggestion i get E16: Invalid range  > wc temp.txt 
  3  80 454 temp.txt

Comment: He means `80|` in normal mode, not `:80|`. Thus, if you wanted to get an X,Y coordinate (e.g. 42,80) you could do `42G80|`. If you want to do this from command-line mode you could do `:norm 42G80|`.

Comment: Thanks, Conner. I wasn't sure how to do exact X,Y either!

Comment: @Conner I like your comment, can you convert your comment to an answer so that I will be more visible ?

Answer (score 94):

Not sure it's in any way more convenient, but you can call the `cursor` function directly:

```
:cal cursor(30, 5)
```

will jump to line 30, column 5.

Comment: more keystrokes than :30<CR> 80|, but cool to know that there's a cursor function!

Comment: This solution is especially nice in combination with the `+...` command line option: it allows a script calling into vim to precisely position the cursor.

Comment: This is especially helpful when writing Vim script.

Answer (score 38):

In command mode:

Type a number followed by G (uppercase) to go to that line number.
Example: 30G goes to line 30.
Example: G goes to the last line of the buffer.

Type a number followed by | (pipe) to go to that column in the current line.
Example: 80| goes to column 80.

So: 30G80| goes to line 30, column 80.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `execute <line_num>`. For example,

```
function GotoLine(line)
     execute a:line
endfunction
```