# jumping to a specific position in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to move my cursor to a specific position, lets say line 64 
and column 40. Is there a way to do that on the command line.

What I normally do:

```
:64
40|
```

but is there a way to combine these two commands into one such that I can type 
everything on the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to learn vimscript and write a function.

Comment: You can also look into the EasyMotion package for this sort of thing: [here](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is given in an answer to "[How do I move the cursor to a specific row and column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767956/moving-the-cursor-to-a-spefic-column-vim)".

Specifically:

> Thus, if you wanted to get an X,Y coordinate (e.g. 42,80) you could do `42G80|`. If you want to do this from command-line mode you could do `:norm 42G80|`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use proper VimL instead of dropping back to normal mode via `:normal`, you could do:

`:call cursor(64, 40)`

Comment: This is also mentioned in another answer in that link (although they mis-spelled "call")